# Extract MathML Equation from MS Word document and convert to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, mathml, mathtype

I have a MS word docx file, I have inserted certain MathML equations inside the doc using MathType library. Now, I want to write a program which can extract these equations(eg. `<math>....</math>`) from doc and put it into a XML file which further will be used into an html page. I am able to identify the equations using microsoft.office.interop.word.document library, but unable to extract the corresponding equation in MathML format. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear (MathML and DOCX (OOXML) are already XML) and too broad as currently stated.

Comment: Mathml equations are added from mathtype plugin and i want to programmatically read these equtions in mathml format.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/PLOS/mathtype/ ?

Comment: Do you get the MathML you require as part of the result of Selection.Range.WordOpenXML?